# File Upload with Angular 6 towards a Flask (Python) Webservice

Tags: angular, flask

I created a webservice with flask to save files, which strongly follows the officially flask [example](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/fileuploads/):

```
@app.route('/parse_table', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    print(request.files)
    # check if the post request has the file part
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        print('no file in request')
        return""
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        print('no selected file')
        return""
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        print("hello")
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        return ""
    print("end")
    return""
```

When I simply using forms in my webapp the service works perfectly (file will be stored on server)

```
<form action = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/parse_table" method = "POST"
      enctype = "multipart/form-data">
  <input type = "file" name = "file" /        
  <input type = "submit"/>
</form>
```

---

**When trying to handle the upload via Angular `HttpClient`, flask detects no file in request (i.e. `print('no file in request')` will be executed)**

*component.html*

```
<input #fileInput name="file" type="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
<button mat-raised-button class="standard-button" (click)="uploadFile()">Upload file</button>
```

*component.ts*

```
  @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput;
  uploadFile() {
    const files: FileList = this.fileInput.nativeElement.files;
    if (files.length === 0) {
      return;
    };

    this.backendCommunicationService.parseTable(files).subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

*backend-communication.service.ts*

```
parseTable(files) {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    })
  };
  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', files[0], files[0].name);
  return this.http.post(this.backendAddress + '/parse_table', formData, httpOptions)
}
```

Any suggestions/ hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the httpOptions; e.g., the explicitly set http header, solves the problem. Comparing the HTTP post requests from angular webapp and from the html form showed, that in the http header Content-Type despite `multipart/form-data'` a boundary is needed, which will be not set by angular, when the http header is explicitly set. Removing this from the http post solves the isuue:

```
parseTable(files) {
  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', files[0], files[0].name);
  return this.http.post(this.backendAddress + '/parse_table', formData);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I just encounter the same issue , may I ask you why it works after removing the headers staff? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are using one of `multipart/*` content types, you are actually required to specify the `boundary` parameter in the `Content-Type` header, otherwise the server (in the case of an HTTP request) will not be able to parse the payload.

From [RFC2046](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt):

> The Content-Type field for multipart entities requires one parameter,
>   "boundary". The boundary delimiter line is then defined as a line
>   consisting entirely of two hyphen characters ("-", decimal value 45)
>   followed by the boundary parameter value from the Content-Type header
>   field, optional linear whitespace, and a terminating CRLF.
>
> Boundary delimiters must not appear within the encapsulated material,
>   and must be no longer than 70 characters, not counting the two leading
>   hyphens.
>
> The boundary delimiter line following the last body part is a
>   distinguished delimiter that indicates that no further body parts will
>   follow. Such a delimiter line is identical to the previous delimiter
>   lines, with the addition of two more hyphens after the boundary
>   parameter value.

Hence, your request should look like

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; --unique-boundary-1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="download.jpg"

--unique-boundary-1
```

Look at the Content-Type and Form Data in the image below

[image]

In angular, best way to achieve this is by not including `Content-Type` in `HttpHeaders`. Let the browser add it for you based on your content.

```
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        // 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', // comment this out
        Authorization: this.userAuthContent
    })
};
```

HTML

```
<input type="file" placeholder="Select images" accept="image/*" multiple
          (change)="changeInFileInput($event.target.files)">
```

Typescript

```
changeInFileInput(files: any): void {
    if (files) {
        // iterate over all the files
        Array.from(files).forEach((fileData: File) => {
            // upload using promise
            this.uploadImage(fileData.file)
                .then((response: any) => {
                    // ...
                })
                .catch((error: any) => {
                    // ...
                });
        });
    }
}

uploadImage(fileToUpload: File): Promise < any > {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // create form data
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    // append image file to it
    formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    // attach formData (just created above) and httpOptions (created earlier) to post request
    this.httpClient.post(environment.bapiurls.uploadRefImage, formData, httpOptions)
      .subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
            resolve(response);
        },
        (error: any) => {
            reject(error);
        });
  });
}
```